# Laravel filter results with dropdown menu

Tags: laravel

I am showing abstracts from my database and I want to filter them using drop-down menu.

I have already created the drop-down menu with the categories which are Medicine and Nursing

my view which includes the drop-down menu

```
<div class="dropdown">

  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data- 
  toggle="dropdown" value="">Show all</button>

     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
         @foreach ($schools as $school)

             <li value="{{ $school->id }}"><a href="{{$school->School_ID}}">{{ $school->School_Type }}</a></li>

         @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

My controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $schools = School::all();
    $items = $request->items ?? 5;      // get the pagination number or a default
    $abstracts = Project::orderBy('A_ID','asc')->paginate($items);

    return view ('Abstracts.index')->with ('abstracts', $abstracts)
                ->withItems($items)
                ->with('schools',$schools);
}
```

can someone guide how to route it properly

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Is there a `school()` relationship function available on your `Project` model?

Comment: I can't route it to the filtered page

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $schools = School::all();
    $items = $request->items ?? 5;      // get the pagination number or a default
    $abstracts = Project::orderBy('A_ID','asc')->paginate($items);

    return view ('Abstracts.index')->with([
           'abstracts' => $abstracts,
           'items' => $items,
           'schools' => $schools
    ]);
}
```

And in your view, you can confirm it like:

```
@foreach ($schools as $school)
    {{ $school }}
@endforeach
```